# CSS images path in eclipse

Tags: css

The following is the screen shot of the project structure , please guide me how to specify the image path url

[image]

```
body  {
            background-image: url(../WebContent/css/Expenses2.jpg);

         }
```

On giving the above path the jpg file does not come as the background colour.

Comment: Where is the css? Is it the table.css?

Comment: No.. in expenses.jsp .. I am trying to add the body background as expenses2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `css` folder is in the same folder as your expenses.jsp file you should just be able to do

```
css/Expenses2.jpg
```

So

```
body  {
    background-image: url(css/Expenses2.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the ... from the url, with ... you are switching to an parent folder

```
body {
  background-image: url(/WebContent/css/Expenses2.jpg); 
}
```

Or

```
body {
  background-image: url(css/Expenses2.jpg); 
}
```